# Unicode Character “⌙” (U+2319) flipped on windows

Tags: css, unicode, character

On my site i have element with `::after` css pseudo that uses the "⌙" character as content:

```
.tags_checks label::after{
content:"⌙"
}
```

Now it works great on mac chrome. but when displayed on windows chrome it is flipped horizontally (and it is like that in the source code):

Mac (Chrome DevTools):

[image]

Windows (Chrome DevTools):

[image]

Why is that and how can i make it consist on both mac and windows?

Comment: Try to change font, and check. To me it seems mostly a font issue. Else check if you have a different direction (right to left) nearby.

Comment: Thanks @GiacomoCatenazzi, but i tried playing with 'direction: rtl / ltr' and changing to every possible font-family and it doesn't make any difference to the flipping problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Python script for tesing purposes and here's the result (`FontGlyphsHtml.py 0x2319` on Windows 10, default browser Chrome)

[image: FontGlyphsHtml.py 0x2319]

The script (partially documented in comments):

```
import unicodedata
import sys
import os
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont, TTCollection

def char_in_font(unicode_char, font):
  for cmap in font['cmap'].tables:
    if cmap.isUnicode() or cmap.getEncoding() == 'utf_16_be':
      if ord(unicode_char) in cmap.cmap:
        auxcn =  cmap.cmap[ord(unicode_char)]
        return auxcn if auxcn != '' else '<nil>'
  return ''

def checkfont(char,font,fontdict,fontpath):
    nameID_index = 1          # works generally (not always)
    for i,f in enumerate(font['name'].names):
        # An Introduction to TrueType Fonts: A look inside the TTF format
        # https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=IWS-Chapter08
        # 1 = Font Family name, 2 = Font SubFamily name, 4 = Full font name
        if f.nameID == 1:
            nameID_index = i
            break
    fontname = font['name'].names[nameID_index].toStr()
    if fontname not in fontdict.keys():
        aux = char_in_font(char, font)
        if aux != '':
          fontdict[fontname] = "{} ({}) {}     [{}] '{}'".format(
            char,
            '0x{:04x}'.format(ord(char)),
            unicodedata.name(char, '???'),
            aux,
            fontname
            )

def testfont(char):
    fontdict = {}
    for fontpath in fontsPaths:
        font = TTFont(fontpath)   # specify the path to the font
        checkfont(char,font,fontdict,fontpath)
    for fontpath in fontcPaths:   # specify the path to the font collection
        fonts = TTCollection(fontpath)
        for ii in range(len(fonts)):
          font = TTFont(fontpath, fontNumber=ii)   # fontfile and index 
          checkfont(char,font,fontdict,fontpath)
    return fontdict

def testprint(char):
    chardesc = '0x{:04x}'.format(ord(char)), unicodedata.name(char, '???')
    charline = '{}  {}  '.format( char, chardesc)
    print('')        # empty line for better readability
    print(charline)
    outfile.write('\n' + htmchar.format(char, chardesc) + '\n')
    fontarray = testfont(char)
    for x in fontarray.keys():
        print(fontarray[x])
        outfile.write(htmline.format(x, fontarray[x]) + '\n')
            
### if __name__ == '__main__':
fontsPaths = []
fontcPaths = []
fontsdirs = [ os.path.join( os.getenv('SystemRoot'), 'Fonts')
              , r"D:\Downloads\MathJax-TeX-fonts-otf"
              , r"D:\Downloads\Fonty"
              # , r"D:\Downloads\Fonty\KrutiDev010\k010"
              # , os.path.join( os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA'), r'Microsoft\Windows\Fonts')
              # , os.path.join( os.getenv('ProgramFiles'), r'WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.4.3243.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe')
            ]
print(fontsdirs, file=sys.stderr)
for fontsdir in fontsdirs:
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk( fontsdir ):
      for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".ttf") or file.endswith(".otf") or file.endswith(".ttc"):
          tfile = os.path.join(root,file)
          if file.endswith(".ttc"):
            fontcPaths.append(tfile)
          else:
            fontsPaths.append(tfile)

htmfile = 'CharGlyphs.html'                                   ### ### ### ###
htmpref = '''
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="generator" content="{}"><title></title>
</head><body>
'''.format(os.path.basename(__file__))
htmchar = '<BR>{} <font color="Red">{}</font><BR>' # line
# htmchar = '<BR>{}<BR>'                           # line
htmline = '<font face="{}">{}</font><BR>'          # font, line
htmsuff = '</body></html>'

outfile = open(htmfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
outfile.write(htmpref + '\n')

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    testprint(u"अ")      # अ  0x0905  Devanagari Letter A
    # testprint(u"")   #  0x1f63a  SMILING CAT FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH
    # testprint(u"")   #  0x1f408  CAT
    # surprising results (characters from the `Private Use` area)
    # testprint("\uf0a3")#   0xf0a3  ???
    # testprint("\uf098")#   0xf098  ???
    # testprint("\uEE79\uED5F") # [uniEE79] 'Segoe MDL2 Assets'
else:
    for i in range( 1, len(sys.argv) ):
        if len(sys.argv[i]) >=2:
          try:
            chars =  chr(int(sys.argv[i]))      # 0x042F or 1071
          except:
            try:
              chars =  chr(int(sys.argv[i],16)) # 042F
            except:
              chars = (sys.argv[i].
                encode('raw_unicode_escape').
                decode('unicode_escape'))       # ➕\U00010A30\u042F\xFE
        else:
            chars = sys.argv[i]                 # Я (Cyrillic Capital Letter Ya)
        for char in chars:
            testprint(char)

outfile.write(htmsuff)
outfile.close()
os.startfile(htmfile)
```

You can test yourself all **Not Sign**s excerpted from [UnicodeData.Txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt):

```
Char CodePoint Category       Description
---- --------- --------       -----------
   ¬ U+00AC    Sm-MathSymbol  Not Sign
   ⌐ U+2310    So-OtherSymbol Reversed Not Sign
   ⌙ U+2319    So-OtherSymbol Turned Not Sign
   ⫬ U+2AEC    Sm-MathSymbol  Double Stroke Not Sign
   ⫭ U+2AED    Sm-MathSymbol  Reversed Double Stroke Not Sign
   ￢ U+FFE2    Sm-MathSymbol  Fullwidth Not Sign
```

Comment: Wow, thanks @JosefZ, but what does it mean? :)

Comment: Definitely, it's mostly a font issue (thanks to comment by @GiacomoCatenazzi). Apparently, some fonts have _Turned_  by vertical axis, the others horizontally…

Comment: Thanks $JosefZ, but how could it be that the same font shows one way on mac and another on windows?

Comment: @mondi: use a webfont, so you have control on it (it should use exactly the same font on every system/browser). fonts.google.com has an extensive list of free fonts to be used on web

Comment: Result of my script shows (in red on the 1st line) how browser renders a glyph using its default (not changed) font…

Comment: As i said i tried using other fonts (google fonts also) and nothing worked.